# Oracle Backup/Recovery architecture

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery

When we write the following:

```
allocate channel ch1_tape type sbt;
set controlfile autobackup format for device type sbt to '%F';
restore controlfile  from autobackup;
RELEASE CHANNEL ch1_tape;
```

By what variables does RMAN search the backups? I think just by DBID, am I wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a modern release (>= 10g) and the usage of a Recovery Area (DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST is set), the initialization parameter **DB_UNIQUE_NAME** (derived from DB_NAME if not specified explicitly) tells RMAN in what subdirectory of the Recovery Area the controlfile autobackup must be searched for.
Without usage of Recovery Area, and in status NOMOUNT (no controlfile is opened), you must set **DBID** for RMAN in order to enable it to retrieve the right controlfile autobackup.